# Problems accesing magento admin panel

Tags: magento, magento2

I am new to magento. I installed magento in my local, everything went well and i am able to access the front end, but not able to access magento admin. The error says "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" and also url turns like this (duplicating index and admin)

"http://localhost/admin/admin/index/index/key/4fc36624617a56db5abdb997f66cdaed0fdb82d106757c18193fe6666f2ae17e/"

Can someone help me with what is going wrong?

Comment: Don't use localhost for your domain name. Either use the IP address or have a domain name entry in your hosts file that points to a virtual host at that IP address. Set the BaseURLs in the database to match.

Comment: @FiascoLabs already done it, after doint it i already saw the login but i cant login, the page doesnt react in nothing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?